# Pdf to image converter library for .net 4.0

Tags: .net

am looking for a dll file, that will convert **pdf files to images.** 
It should work with .net  Framework, win 32 nit and also 64 bit machines upto windows 7.
Please tell me any suggestion

Comment: try searching first. question shows no effort or research

Comment: If you google you will find a bunch..First try to search and come here  and then say us what have you tried definitely we will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) will help you...

You have to write `convert "PDF FILE NAME" "IMAGE FILE NAME"` in the command prompt after adding this..